# Translucent material with outlines (in UE4).... How do I do this?

Tags: unreal-4, materials

I have been trying to create a material like this in Unreal Engine 4.27 but I can't seem to find any resources on how to do this. The goal is to use this material on any 3D model to give it transparency but also an outline that is visible through the model. The image attached is create to illustrate the idea of it. Thanks!
[image: Image generated to illustrate the idea...]

Comment: How should the shader know which triangle boundaries to draw with outlines, and which to leave unlined?

Comment: Sounds like a task for the geometry shader. I'm using OpenGL myself, but I'm sure that UE supports the geometry shaders., or something like it. In OpenGL, you can pass in triangle adjacency data, and then skip drawing lines for coplanar faces. Sorry if this is  not helpful.

Comment: @DMGregory Edge detection?

Comment: An edge detection shader usually works on the rendered result as a flat image with a single layer of depth/normals, so it would not be suitable for finding edges on the far side.

Comment: I tried a dual material. One with 'TwoSidedSign' node in opacity and one with normal translucency. I also tried to use AO to display the edge, but I am not that clever yet.